# MODE with SUMPRODUCT formula

Tags: google-sheets, formula, mode

I am trying to find a mode of weekdays (Monday, Tuesday, etc.) within a date range by using the formula:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(MODE(SUMPRODUCT(--(AgendaData!$A:$A>=A$6),--(AgendaData!$B:$B<=B$6),AgendaData!$F:$F)))`

The error reads: "MODE cannot produce a result. No values occur more than once."

I think it has something to do with the F column being in text format. I want the result to show the mode of the weekday in text. I wonder what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Doesn't "No values occur more than once" explain what the issue is?

Comment: I see in Column F: Monday, Tuesday, Monday, Thursday, Wednesday.

It will not show the result as "Monday" when there are actually two Mondays and that will be the mode.

I think it is misunderstanding the column since it is searching for numbers not text.

Comment: Indeed, `mode` ignores all strings; it's a numeric function. So does `sumproduct`, incidentally. And I'm unclear on how `mode(sumproduct(...))` is supposed to function, considering sumproduct returns a single value.

Comment: Okay, Let me clarify my question: I would like to filter the data to the start and end dates I set and find the mode of the weekday (text format) in column F. Maybe I am using totally wrong formula for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the mode of text values by converting them to numbers, finding the mode, and converting back. It's convenient to use a three-column lookup table for this, e.g.,

```
Monday      1   Monday
Tuesday     2   Tuesday
Wednesday   3   Wednesday
Thursday    4   Thursday
Friday      5   Friday
Saturday    6   Saturday
Sunday      7   Sunday
```

Let's say this table is in columns I:K, and your data is in column F. Then the following finds its mode:

```
=vlookup(mode(arrayformula(iferror(vlookup(F:F, I:J, 2, false)))), J:K, 2)
```

Here, `arrayformula(iferror(vlookup...` is conversion to numeric, using the part I:J of the table, and ignoring blank cells and anything that isn't a day of week. After `mode` is applied, `vlookup` converts the number back to text using the part J:K of the table.

Comment: Perfect! This is what I am looking for, zaq! May I have your brain?

Answer (score 0):

To check it out, you may use formula:

```
=filter(AgendaData!$F:$F,AgendaData!$A:$A>=A$6,AgendaData!$B:$B<=B$6)
```

You'll see all matching values from column F and will know exactly if some values occur more than once.